# How to test app on Ipod Touch from xcode 4.3.1?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I am very new to iOS development. I am developing an app, currently i am testing it on emulator. Now i need to test the app on ipod touch. I have tried to test but it says

`The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in the default keychain`

**I am looking for steps or any posts.**Much appreciated.

I got Apple developer License .

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: There will be a private key associated with every provision profile. You have to install that private key in your system's key-chain.

Comment: thanks i am really very new.. this is my first time.. could you post some links how to do that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to jump through a big hoop :) Code Signing

1. You'll need to get a developer certificate.
   Go to applications / utilities and run Keychain Access.

[image]

Request a Certificate From a CA 
Follow those instruction.
This certifies you.

Next, certify your device.

1. login to your developer account.
2. Go to the Provisioning portal (link from main dev. page)
3. Left side > Devices (you can get the UUID from iTunes or from Xcode organizer).
   Add your device. Download the device certificate. Double click it to add it to Xcode.

Certify your App.

Same page in the Provisioning Portal.

Get new app id.

Then go to Provisioning.

Repeat the certificate process to get a developer distribution certificate for your app.

Download these, and see how things look in Xcode Organizer.

Finally, in the main code page of the app itself:

[image]

see if you can set the code signing to your developer certificate.

You will know when this is all set, as when you look at Xcode schemes, you should see you iPod listed.

[image]

You'll probably get stuck at various points in this process. I did. You might want to ask (or look for) a specific question, whether it's the AppID, the Developer Cert, or code signing.

There are some videos on the Apple site, but they are using an older version of Xcode..

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Vinoth..  I also suggest noting which Apple ID corresponds with which app. Remember, it's not you.. This system is really  difficult to navigate. Also, be careful with the AppID. You will be stuck with it, as AFAIK, there is no way to delete them. Certificates can be edited, revoked, or downloaded. If you mess up the AppID, just make a new one.

Comment: One more thing. Everything above is for development - so you can test your app on your devices. You will have to go through most of this again when you are ready to put your app up for sale.. The first is Development Certificate process, later, it's the Distribution Certificate process. phew !!

Comment: Thanks again for valuable information.. yeah it really messy.. i just  uploaded the certificate and waiting for upproval from Apple.. how long it takes to approve David

Comment: While adding provisioning profile to xcode it says valid signing identity not found.. i am not sure what was the exact problem.. could you help ne please

Comment: On the first question, as soon as it says pending, refresh the screen and the profile should be ready for download. On the second point, you have to ensure that your developer certificate, the app id match, and the provisioning profile match. I find it best sometimes to delete all the profiles that say "invalid" and start again.

Comment: Thanks David i solved that problem.. just a simple mistake i haven't double clicked the provisioning file.. working now thanks